# why not get correctly date, (plus 1 day) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get tomorrow date, but this work not correctly. I dont understand, which problem is here, I split date, for getting true date format, check if checkbox checked and add to getdate 1 day, and shape date as i want

```
function doLateCheckOut(checkbox){
    var end_date = $('[name="end_date"]').val();
    var dateArr = end_date.split(".");
    var date = new Date(dateArr[2]+'-'+dateArr[1]+'-'+dateArr[0]);

    if(checkbox.checked) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

    }
    else{

        date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    }

    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    day = day + '';

    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    if (monthIndex < 10) {
        monthIndex = "0" + (monthIndex+1);
    }

    var latedate = day + "." + monthIndex + "." + year;

    $('[name="end_date"]').val(latedate);
    console.log(latedate);

}
```

Comment: what error or wrong date you are getting? you must know that the monthIndex in date starts from 0. And I will suggest using [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for the requirement.

Comment: Can you please post the error so we can analyze what could be incorrect

Comment: Yes, sure I use  month index not correctly, but it also not work correctly, get 2 day after... I havent error, i get wrong date.

Comment: I dont know why, but i get 1 day before from new Date()